# Strange problem with synchronized clipboards

Tags: clipboard, nautilus, parcellite

I'm using Parcellite with synchronized clipboards and I ran into a funny problem: I can't use clipboard for renaming a file with Nautilus. Anytime I press <kbd>F2</kbd> the basename of the file gets selected thus overwriting my clipboard content. I can't even use Parcellite's history, since pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> open the history window, lets me re-select what I want, but Nautilus loses focus and the rename action is over. How to solve it?

Is there a clipboard manager having a key combination allowing to scroll through the clipboard history, similar to <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> (yank-pop) in Emacs?